# Why is my transformed hamburger menu close button uneven?

Tags: html, css, transform, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to create a hamburger menu in which after you click it, it turns into a close ("X") button.  So I put together this HTML for the hamburger menu

```
<div id="mobile-nav">

        <div class="menuContainer">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>

     <nav>
           <a href='#'>Vote</a>
           <a href='#'>Search</a>
           <a href='#'>Contact</a>
     </nav>
</div>
```

and these styles

```
.menuContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 25px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

However, when I click on the button, the "X" seems cut off on the right side -- https://jsfiddle.net/8jvrrcqq/3/ .  What can I do to make the X even on both the left and right sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just needed to tweak your translate values a bit. Also consider that you can use `translateY` and `rotateZ` since you only care about these directions for the animation.

```js
 $('.close-btn').click(function() {
   $('.responsive-menu').removeClass('expand')
   $('.menu-btn').removeClass('btn-none')
 })

 $('.menuContainer').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('change');
   $('nav').toggleClass('nav-open');
 });
```

```css
#mobile-nav {
  display: block;
}

.menuContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  transform: translateY(9px) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  transform: translateY(-9px) rotateZ(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mobile-nav">
  <div class="menuContainer">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `transform: translate` amounts need to be adjusted. I have adjusted them below; feel free to adjust more as needed.

```js
$('.close-btn').click(function() {
    $('.responsive-menu').removeClass('expand')
    $('.menu-btn').removeClass('btn-none')
})

$('.menuContainer').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('change');
    $('nav').toggleClass('nav-open');
});
```

```css
#mobile-nav {
    display: block;
}
.menuContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
    width: 25px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 4px);
}
.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-9px, -5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="mobile-nav">
    <div class="menuContainer">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <a href='#'>Vote</a>
        <a href='#'>Search</a>
        <a href='#'>Contact</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```